# Should we accept questions about identifying colors?

Tags: discussion

It's the second question these past few days about identifying colors. Before the case gets made in comments, I would like to hear the community as to how these should be treated. Do you believe they are a good fit or no? Should these have guidelines like font-identification?

Are there cases where questions like these would be ok?

[Do colors like these have a specific name OR special "category" of names for each?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147712/do-colors-like-these-have-a-specific-name-or-special-category-of-names-for-eac)

[What color is the color coral, exactly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147765/what-color-is-the-color-coral-exactly)

Comment: I think some questions can be opinion based, like color questions, but other questions but not be as okay.

Comment: It seems most users agree that we can't answer the question "exactly what color is X?". But I can imagine other questions which are more about the *origin* of color names which would be alright.

Answer (score 1):

I belive we should to some extent. Sometimes the question may be worth it.

Color has a lot of suprises, so much so that pople often refuse to believe you.

Colors dont have names. I mean very broad categories of color ranges have names, like say Red, Blue, Green, and Yellow. But these colors dont have a exact taxonomy. So for example Pink is mostly subset of Red colors. So saying that this shirt is pink and another person saying that the shirt is red is totally acceptable.

I get that most people have this object → property → name kind ow worldview. But color is not a simple property like say weight its a extremely complex property.

So thertefore a naive "question what is the name of this color" has as much of an answer as "how nice is the softness of this pillow". The best we can say is that a color name is more like a description for some feeling, wague overlapping and lacking any objective reality.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is: The questions like I asked a few days ago and Devils_Spawn asked can be allowed, because in my case, I specifically asked if such a *category* exists or not. Further, I find nothing wrong in knowing *common* names of some colors. It's not really opinion based. I would find it strange if someone tells me that your avatar (my old avatar) color doesn't have a name. I mean you can't call it something.

I feel Devils_Spawn question could also be answered, because I think all he wanted to know which is the closest color to that palette. It wasn't opinion based.

Of course, some users might perceive colors differently, but in general, as a graphic designer, your clients (at least in my culture) expect you to know *common* names. For example if he asks what is the color in my avatar. I can't say him it's opinion based. I would like to tell him truth, if not exact color name. For example, the truth like - the color of my avatar is between blue and green.

Similarly, for Devils_Spawn, even Wikipedia is *saying* it is shade of orange. And I think that would be a sufficient answer to that particular question.